# Solve function returning symbol

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use the MATLAB Symbolic Math Toolbox to solve simple equations, but I am not receiving the expected/desired result.

I'm using Windows 10, and this is the output of entering `ver` into the Command Window:

```matlab
    MATLAB Version: 9.6.0.1335978 (R2019a) Update 8
    MATLAB License Number: STUDENT
    Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Version 10.0 (Build 19041)
    Java Version: Java 1.8.0_181-b13 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    MATLAB                                                Version 9.6         (R2019a)
    Simulink                                              Version 9.3         (R2019a)
    Control System Toolbox                                Version 10.6        (R2019a)
    Curve Fitting Toolbox                                 Version 3.5.9       (R2019a)
    DSP System Toolbox                                    Version 9.8         (R2019a)
    Data Acquisition Toolbox                              Version 4.0         (R2019a)
    Image Processing Toolbox                              Version 10.4        (R2019a)
    Instrument Control Toolbox                            Version 4.0         (R2019a)
    Optimization Toolbox                                  Version 8.3         (R2019a)
    Parallel Computing Toolbox                            Version 7.0         (R2019a)
    Signal Processing Toolbox                             Version 8.2         (R2019a)
    Simulink Control Design                               Version 5.3         (R2019a)
    Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox               Version 11.5        (R2019a)
    Symbolic Math Toolbox                                 Version 8.3         (R2019a)
```

According to the in-app documentation, the `solve` function should follow this syntax:

```matlab
    syms x
    eqn = sin(x) == 1;
    solx = solve(eqn, x)
```

And the expected output from this is:

```
solx =

                                       pi/2
```

However, when I run the same commands I receive:

```matlab
    >> syms x
    >> eqn = sin(x) == 1;
    >> solx = solve(eqn, x)
     
    solx =
     
                                           x
```

I have tried a number of even simpler equations with the same result (receiving symbol instead of a numerical value).
What am I doing incorrectly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Funny, my MATLAB (also R2019) returns `pi/2` for your example. Does your `which solve` point to `.../toolbox/symbolic/symbolic/solve.m`?

Comment: `which solve` returns `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\toolbox\maple\solve.m`. Interesting that our paths are different, but they seem to be pointing to the same `.m` file.

Comment: Oh no, this doesn't look like the same file at all. What is this `maple` toolbox, does it have something to do with the famous Maplesoft program? Anyway, you could try running `p=path();path(p,'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\toolbox\maple')` to send this maple folder to the end of the MATLAB search path; `solve(eqn, x)` should then hopefully behave as expected. But it is possible that unexpected things in the `maple` toolbox might break after this change...

Comment: This worked! Thank you @Vicky. It didn't seem to affect "solve" functionality in Maplesoft either. Editing post to include solution.

Comment: Don't edit the solution into your question. Post the solution as answer

Comment: @JHBonarius will do, thanks. New to this site. How can I make sure Vicky receives maximum reputation for her answer?

Comment: By convincing @Vicky to put it in an answer and accepting it. However if he/she/they don't want that, thats his/her/their own decision.

Comment: @Vicky feel free to post your response as an answer and I'll accept it. I'll go ahead and post it but won't accept my own answer just yet.

Comment: Okay, I just posted it! (BTW: when I said "unexpected things might break", I meant other functions inside `...\toolbox\maple`, not the "real" Maple itself!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, your MATLAB installation does not seem to use the function in `...\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\solve.m` when a `solve` command is issued; instead, an unrelated function provided by the `maple` toolbox is used, leading to some confusion. This issue can be solved by reordering the MATLAB search path:

```
p=path();
path(p,'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\toolbox\maple');
```